# How Unity editor shows transform in scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm creating a 2D game. It was configured as a 2D game since it was created.

When I selected a `GameObject`, in the scene their **anchor**, their **size** and their **pivots** were pointed out.

Suddenly this has changed, and it appears like if it were a 3D project, with a circle and all the axis around it, whatever GameObject I select. (Pic below)

How can I configure my Unity Editor to be like before? Maybe is worth it to say that in the top toolbar of `Scene` window there's still `2D` mode selected:

[image]

Version: Unity 2018.3.14f1

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set the `Rotation Tool`. I think you were using `Move Tool` before.
It's just a matter of which gizmo you see in the scene.

You may just press "W" on the keyboard.

Or press the `Move Tool` (first one in the images).

[image]

Further info on [Unity Tools](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html).

Comment: That's it! Although `Q` took me to `Hand Tool` instead of `Move Tool` btw.

Comment: I confirm, for the Move Tool it's the 'W' (not the Q).